# How to run python code with root permissions in sourced environment

Tags: python, permissions, virtualenv, chroot

I have created pyenv environment (`/home/username/python_env/`) with some additional libraries (like PyYaml, Pillow etc).
Everything is working fine until I need to change `/etc/resolv.conf` from inside of my tool. Additional part of code which I need to run is `os.chroot` and I can't do it without root permissions.

All operations are made for current user (which can change) so if I use `sudo` to execute my tool like `sudo python src/tool-name/main.py` then everything will be executed for root user instead for `username`.

Using sudo will affects:

- error while starting my tool because sudo will force to use system python known to root user (instead of sources earlier `venv`)
- after I source virtual environment as a root and execute my tool all files which I will create will have root permissions

Is there a way to request sudo just for small part of code and after that return to user permissions while my script is running?

Comment: Up to my knowledge no.

you cann call a subprocess with sudo, that just performs part of the work and then execute the rest in your script.
Not very elegant though

Or you could have two processes that communicate with each other
one with sodu the other without, but also not so easy and if you don't pay attention a potential security risk

Comment: Are you sure you need to run `os.chroot`? That does not change your user to root, it changes the root for absolute paths. In my experience most people who say they need `os.chroot` do so because they misunderstand what it does.

Comment: I'm changing path from current folder to jail in created partition so... yes :(

Answer (score 0):

Running Python code with root permissions inside a virtual environment can be tricky, as you need to maintain the environment variables of the virtual environment while executing the code with elevated privileges. Here's a possible approach to achieve this:

1. Activate the virtual environment in your user context.
2. Use `sudo -E` to run the Python code with elevated privileges while
   preserving the environment variables.

Step 1: Activate the virtual environment (as a regular user):

> `$ source /home/username/python_env/bin/activate`

Step 2: Run your Python code with `sudo -E`:

> `$ sudo -E python /path/to/your/code.py`

The `-E` option tells sudo to preserve the user's environment, including the virtual environment variables set during activation.

With this approach, your Python code should be executed with root permissions while still using the virtual environment's Python interpreter and libraries.